# Jenkins upload to S3 (Post build Action)

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

This is my directory path in jenkins **/var/jenkins_home/workspace/automation**.

1.) I am trying to upload the contents in the automation folder to my S3 bucket. When I set the source and destination, I could only upload files but not the folders inside my automation directory.

2.) When I upload all the files are stored in S3Bucket/jobs/automation/BUILD-NUMBER/MY-FILES. Whereas I need my files in the S3Bucket root.

Answer (score 2):

To void this problem you need to uncheck "Manage artifacts" in S3 Plugin upload options. In this case files will be uploaded directly to bucket root.

Comment: It worked ! ! Thanks. Still the folders are not getting upload to the s3 bucket.

Comment: you can mark this answer as correct ;)
Did you try to use asterisk? I.e. `/foo/bar/*` instead of `/foo/bar`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Does it work now? If it still doesn't work you can 1) try two ** on the end 2) create a ticket in Jenkins Jira (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org).

Comment: I tried unchecking "Manage artifacts", but my files were still uploaded to S3Bucket/jobs/automation/BUILD-NUMBER/MY-FILES, rather than the S3Bucket root.  Is there a way to solve this issue - outlined in 2) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **aws S3 cp** from bash command -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

PLS make sure to install the aws cli on the slave that runs the job

Mor

Comment: When I tried executing post build script (**aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket** or **aws S3 cp**), I am getting **aws not found** (which means, I don't have aws cli plugin installed in jenkins). I tried searching the plugin, but no go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Flatten Directories' in case you don't want the directory structure in your S3 bucket.